Is there any less privileged role than manage-users for realm-management client.?
We have created a custom user role in our custom realm by name custom user, this role has a realm-management permission/role view-users along with other role specific to the product. We have a user settings UI screen, and we want the user to be able to update their own password, email, firstName etc from this screen. This is not possible through only one permission view-users, when we add manage-users role it works fine. But the downside here is that with manage-users, this user can escalate its privileges to another powerful user role like custom admin which we have defined and acts like a super user.
Is there any way to achieve this? I have tried adding account level permissions like manage-account, view-profile etc. But without manage-users nothing works for me.
Any guidance here would be helpful.
